# Refresh another app silently

Tags: ios

Is there anyway I could refresh the built-in Apple **Mail** based on an event in **My App**?

So,:

1. **My App** is not running on the user's phone.
2. It waits to receives a silent (without an alert) push notification.
3. It pulls data and based on certain conditions an event is triggered.
4. Refresh (not launch) the **Mail** app so it can receive its own push notifications itself.

So essentially everything happens in the background with **Mail** app eventually receiving the push notification of a new mail as it would receive or fetch or manual refresh.

I read the [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) page but it doesn't answer my question so I'm wondering if its even possible.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?  What is app `XYZ`?  Are you talking about a system app like the calendar?

Comment: @JAL Apple's default Mail app.

Comment: There is no reason (and I don't think it is possible) to refresh the Mail app.  The user either has manual fetch or push settings for mail.  Are you trying to push a notification to a device, get some information, return that information back to a server and send an email based on that?

Comment: Definitely not possible using public APIs (except you control XYZ too).

Comment: @JAL Thats the thing, its either manual or push but the requirement is to deliver the email to the user almost realtime so I'm looking to refresh the mail app manually.

Comment: I updated the description.

Comment: When Jal said it's manual or push that was a complete list. You wanting something else is irrelevant. Other options are not available. If it's a mail thing then you've no guarantee that the email will be received immediately anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me try to break down what you are asking:

1. My App receives a silent push notification, gets some information, and sends a request to a server (all in the background).
2. When the server receives that request, it sends out an email to the device.
3. You want that email to appear instantly.

Apple does not give developers explicit control to change a user's mail settings.  As a developer you probably won't even know what mail accounts are on the device (or if the user even has the right account available).  I would say that what you are asking is impossible with the current structure of Apple's APIs.

Push notifications in the Mail app do not work like other apps.  Either mail is pushed to the device instantly (the Push switch is enabled), mail is fetched on an interval, or the user manually refreshes the mail every time they open the app.  If the user has Fetch set to manual, they will not get your email.

[image: Fetch]

Comment: Not necessarily a patricular emailm I can safely assume the user has the email account added, its just about refreshing the Mail app so it can receive the push notifications as it would on manual refresh.

Comment: @3zzy Yep, you can't do that.  I'll see if I can scrape together an answer using private APIs but I think that would be a breach of privacy to change the user's mail settings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say *change* user's mail settings, I'm just looking to refresh the mail and that too when I'm sure there is email to be fetched.

Comment: @3zzy Push notifications in the Mail app do not work like other apps.  Either mail is pushed to the device on an interval, or the user manually refreshes the mail every time they open the app.  If the user has Fetch set to manual, they will not get your email.  I will edit my answer to add an image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are many points in what you are asking that may raise some issues:

> My App is not running on the user's phone.
>
> It waits to receives a silent (without an alert) push notification.

If the user has deactivate background mode for your app, your app won't even be notified silently. Nothing will happen.

> It pulls data and based on certain conditions an event is triggered.

Don't forget that you have only 30 sec to perform any requests. If your request take too long, iOS will kill the process.

> Refresh (not launch) the Mail app so it can receive its own push
> notifications itself.

Just not possible at all, maybe with a jailbroken device :D
Apple don't let dev a lot of possibilities with their native apps. You can open the mail app, open a new mail to be send, but that is pretty much all you can do.